# Google SpreadSheets: Can't make a loop of for using setFormula

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I have this fomula

```
function data(){
 var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
 for(i=1;i<=8;i++){  
for(j=1;j<=5;j++){
 sh.getRange(i+4;j+1).setFormula('=split(IMPORTXML(concatenate("https://fiis.com.br/";$A$1);concatenate($A$29;'+ i +';$B$29;'+ j +';$C$29));"()")');

   };

  };

}
```

I'm trying to insert some data from this site in the sheet as a matrix, I've tried a lot of diferents times but it keep me giving "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (line 44, file "teste.gs")Dismiss" line 44 is the one with setFormula.
Pleeease someone save me

Edit: I found the problem : It was here "$A$29;'+ i +';$B$29;'+ j +';$C$29)" I had to take off the spaces after and before + like these:
$A$29;'+i+';$B$29;'+j+';$C$29)
Then it worked

Comment: use `getRange(i+4,j+1).`. `,` not `;`

Answer (score 0):

what is it you are trying to do with `$A$29;'+ i +';$B$29;'+ j +';$C$29`?
seems like it should be `$A$29;"+";i;"+";$B$29;"+";j;"+";$C$29`
or if you want to add that i or j to the cell, then you should do it above that line.